# Events doesn't fire when using UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

What I did is, I have made 2 user controls. One control is inside the other.

NoW one control has a buttton and a data grid and datalist in it. When pressing button I am filling datagrid while datalist visiblity false. This is working fine. But now when I press some link button in datalist data, it should call item_command event but it is not calling.

I have also used a Updatepanel as a wrapper(all controls are inside it).

Please suggest what may be the reason for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the enablePartialRendering to False of the ScriptManager like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
```

Comment: not working. I have applied the scriptmanager to the aspx page where these two controls are used

Comment: there was some other mistake which I did, But also the one mentioned by you. Thanks

Comment: this basically disables AJAX. Why would you want to do this?